# Does broadcast receiver also unregister if service is destroyed

Tags: android

Hi I have `Service` where I am registering the broadcast receiver. I want to know if service is destroyed then broadcast receiver which I am adding is also unregistered or not.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(
            latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
            longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
            radius, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
            -1, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration
            proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
    );

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to documentation - You have to unregister you receivers in `onDestroy` method .

*`onDestroy` is called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed.  The service should clean up any resources it holds (threads, **registered  receivers**, etc) at this point. ...*

Answer (score 1):

Actullay no, where you register and unregister the receiver, for example, if you register a receiver in `onCreate`(Bundle) using the activity's `context`, you should unregister it in `onDestroy()` to prevent leaking the receiver out of the activity context. If you register a receiver in `onResume()`, you should unregister it in `onPause()` to prevent registering it multiple times (If you don't want to receive broadcasts when paused, and this can cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in `onSaveInstanceState`(Bundle), because this isn't called if the user moves back in the history stack. [for more help refer this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)

```
public void unregisterBroadcastReceiver() {

    this.unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);

    Toast.makeText(this, 'unregistered broadcst receiver', Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }
```